# Area 51 Proposal: Sage and its subcomponents

Tags: discussion, area51

I proposed a Q&A site for Sage and all its subcomponents viz. GAP, Pari, Singular, Sympy, ... on Area51 here. I thought many mathematicians here who use Sage in their research and teaching here might be interested in such a site especially because questions related to software aspects are off-topic here.

Here is the Area 51 proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70511/sage

Please go and follow it if you're interested; add example questions and vote up (down) questions that you think should be on-topic (resp. off-topic) for the upcoming site.

/p/s/ I posted to meta.math also on the grounds that asking for explicit software help (non-mathematical questions pertaining to Sage or its subcomponents) is considered off-topic.

Comment: Are you coordinating with William Stein? Are you aware they already have a Q&A site, running on a open source analogue of StackExchange?

Comment: @Scott: Yes, I am aware that we already have a Q&A for sage. The aim of this site is to provide user-support for Sage and ALL its subcomponents under one umbrella. Also, we have had trouble maintaining the askbot site recently; at the moment, not all users can post to it, for example (there is a karma/rep barrier to prevent spamming). This idea came about in a recent trac ticket on which William commented with a +1  and he is now following the proposal; so I guess he is aware. I will be in touch with him about this soon.

Comment: Thanks, @knsam. Without that context I was worried the proposal was inappropriate.

Comment: The proposal has now been deleted, I think due to inactivity before reaching the threshold for activation.